# How to override bootstrap cdn in Django?

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to Django, and even more so to CSS. In the base.html of my site I included a bootstrap cdn as follows:

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{%  static 'favicon.ico' %}">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

However, I want to make some modifictions to the css and I cannot because the cdn is an external file. It wouldn't work when I simply copy the content to a local css file because of proocol issues. 
According to [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305611/bootstrap-cdn-wp-how-to-edit-css/28306264) I've tried to add another line so it would override the cdn, as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/bootstrap/css/style.css">
```

but it doesn't work. I tried also to write this line in a local html file (i.e. not in base.html) but no success. 
My questions are:

1. How do I override the cdn file? That is, also where is it best to
   place the other css file (I have static directories both in project
   and app levels for some reason), and if it matters how it is named?
2. What makes a simple and safe test to see if it worked?
3. Most of all, I'm looking for a way two place to elements (say, an image and a menu) alongside instead of stacked. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545486/html-align-two-elements-on-both-sides-of-the-same-line) seemed relevant, but it requires modifications to the css file, which I can't seem to make.
4. Where should the css links be placed? Like I wrote or inside the meta section?

Comment: ok if all you want to do is putting to elements in one line you don't have to touch bootstrap. The link you provided should tell you what to do. the CSS "float" attribute is probably what you are looking for. Put the two elements in a `<div>` and add the float attribute. Try some stuff to see how CSS works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that you defined STATIC_URL in your settings file

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
2. I would recommend you to read about static file in django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/), in a simple words you should have a structure of your static files, create one folder named "static" inside your project folder and put all of your static files inside decomposed it by folders as well, for example, all your .css files you will put to

   /static/css/main.css

etc.
Then I would hightly recommend using [django.contrib.staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#module-django.contrib.staticfiles)
Finally all you have to do would look like that

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static/css/bootstrap/style.css %)">
```

And remove your cdn link from your code

Comment: thanks! aparently what went wrong was that I wrote `{{ STATIC_URL }}/bootstrap/css/style.css">` instead of `href="{% static "/bootstrap/css/style.css" %}">`. Now I can use both the CDN (which saves me a lot of work - otherwise I would have had to write the entire thing myself) and modify whatever I need (default font, font size, color palette etc.) across the site.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a CSS file under the bootstrap call and override any classes you need to in there.